# How can I set path in sys command to invoke python script from jsp?

Tags: python, jsp

```
.jsp
<%@ page import = "java.io.File"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*"%>
<%
        String dir = "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Venu"
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ImageConversion.py download.jpg", null, dir);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInp$
        String line=reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null)
        {
                System.out.println(line);
                line=reader.readLine();
        }
%>




ImageConversion.py

<%@ page import = "java.io.File"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*"%>
<%
        String dir = "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Venu"
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("download.jpg", null, dir);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInp$
        String line=reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null)
       {
                System.out.println(line);
                line=reader.readLine();
       }
%>
```

I am trying to invoke python script using JSP but the jsp code is showing error and how can we call system command from jsp.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `the jsp code is showing error` Perhaps you could show us the error?

Comment: error = 2 no such file in the directory, I am running my JSP from the cloud

Comment: Is the .py file itself executable?  Perhaps you have to use the Python main program as the first argument.